# Oracle SQL : remove a string from an existing string value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have string in stored in the oracle database that looks like below

```
IDS
---
121,223,423,322
```

What I need is, when an user enters a value, eg. `121`, then it will be remove from the existing string. See sample output below

Scenario 1 :
    Given : 121
    Output : 223,423,322

Scenario 2 :

```
Given : 223
Output : 121,423,322
```

How can I do it in SQL statement? I am looking into using REGEXP_SUBSTR, but not sure how to do... :(

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: append 223 with , and replace?

Comment: nope, remove 223 from "121,223,423,322", for any given ID, remove it from the existing ID list

Comment: select replace('121,223,423,322','223,') from dual;

Comment: that will only work for ID in between, but will not work for the last ID, since there is no comma after the value.

Comment: I think it should also cover a scenario where there is only 1 value.

Comment: select replace(CONCAT('121,223,423,322',','),'121,') from dual; there is an extra "," at the end though, except for when it's 1 value (this might be easier with a function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expression

```
replace(regexp_replace (column, '(,<value>$)|(^<value>,)|(^<value>$)', ''), ',<value>,', ',')
```

For example for value 121:

```
select 
    replace(regexp_replace ('1121,121,223,423,322', '(,121$)|(^121,)|(^121$)', ''), ',121,', ',')    
from dual;
```

Comment: @Ianthe: Previous expression did not works properly for given string `'1121,121'` and value `'121'`. Now it works fine.